# Exchange cookies between requests in OkHttp

Tags: java, web-scraping, okhttp

I'm trying to scrape one website, and for that, I need to exchange the cookies and headers between all the requests.

The question is the following: how can I achieve such behaviour in a smart way, not by resetting the cookies and headers manually between the `Request` and `Response` objects each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a CookieJar. There's an in-memory implementation in the okhttp-urlconnection artifact.

See [Automatic cookie handling with OkHttp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881775/automatic-cookie-handling-with-okhttp-3) for examples

Comment: Can you please provide a short example of how to use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881775/automatic-cookie-handling-with-okhttp-3